# Compiling handlebars templates using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to compile my handlebars template using Grunt as described below. It's okay but it compiles all the hbs files into one file which is not so good. I would like to have a separate file for Menu1 and Menu2 directories. I'd be really great if I could somehow make a separate task for each directory. 
But as I'm still learning this stuff I couldn't find any better way to make it work..
Or perhaps if I could somehow make the Handlebars compile each file separately.

Project tructure:

```
    /js/:
     ->/app/
        app_init.js
     ->/templates/
       -> /Menu1/
           template1.hbs
           template2.hbs
       -> /Menu2/
           template1.hbs
           template2.hbs
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var TEMPLATES_LOCATION        = "./js/templates/",
        TEMPLATES_EXTENSION       = ".hbs",
        TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_LOCATION = TEMPLATES_LOCATION,    
        TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "compiled_templates.js";  

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            handlebars: {
                files: [TEMPLATES_LOCATION + '**/*' + TEMPLATES_EXTENSION],
                tasks: ['handlebars:compile']
            }
        },
        handlebars: {
            compile: {
                src: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + '**/*' + TEMPLATES_EXTENSION,
                dest: TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_LOCATION + TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_FILENAME,
                options: {
                    amd: true,
                    namespace: "templates"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a slight workaround. Not sure if this is the best way to do this but it works..

`handlebars: {
            compile_Menu1: {
                src: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + '/Menu1/*' + TEMPLATES_EXTENSION,
                dest: TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_LOCATION+"Menu1"+TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_EXTENSION,
                options: {
                    amd: true,
                    namespace: "M1_templates"
                }
            },
            compile_Menu2: {
                src: TEMPLATES_LOCATION + '/Menu2/*' + TEMPLATES_EXTENSION,
                dest: TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_LOCATION+"Menu2"+TEMPLATES_OUTPUT_EXTENSION,
                options: {
                    amd: true,
                    namespace: "M2_templates"
                }
            }
        }`